# GNU sed cannot match against last newline in a combined string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The problem is, when all the strings passed are combined into one to match against newlines, if the input had a trailing newline sed has a problem to match against it.

A simple string.

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd" | hexdump -C
00000000  61 61 0a 62 62 0a 63 63  0a 64 64                 |aa.bb.cc.dd|
0000000b
```

In this case, if we need to surround the last two pieces of text with null character instead of newlines, it works fine.

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd" \
  | sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; ${g; s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)$/\1\x00\2\x00\3\x00/; p}' \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  61 61 0a 62 62 00 63 63  00 64 64 00              |aa.bb.cc.dd.|
0000000c
```

But if the input had a trailing newline, appending a trailing `\n` to substitution regexp doesn’t make it match.

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n" \
  | sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; ${g; s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n$/\1\x00\2\x00\3\x00/; p}' \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  61 61 0a 62 62 0a 63 63  0a 64 64 0a              |aa.bb.cc.dd.|
0000000c
```

However, if we haven’t added the trailing newline to regexp, it still matches!

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n" \
  | sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; ${g; s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)$/\1\x00\2\x00\3\x00/; p}' \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  61 61 0a 62 62 00 63 63  00 64 64 00 0a           |aa.bb.cc.dd..|
0000000d
```

But it seems like it just ignores the trailing newline from the input or `$` is somehow matches it itself. I found in [sed FAQ on sourceforge](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html) (§ 5.10) that sed stripes the trailing newline from the line before placing it to the pattern space, and even adds a trailing newline to the output, but, as it can be clearly seen from the second and third examples, it doesn’t do either thing.

So I was reading and reading and returned to thought about the `$` is somehow matches against that trailing `\n` itself. If I understood info page correctly, it should—when in multiline mode, i.e. when substitution has the `M` or `m` modifier. But it didn’t. There were also mentioned combinations like `\´` (actually grave mark) and `\'` (straight single quote), that should match buffer boundaries in multiline mode, but they do not work in my shell (GNU bash-1.4.45) as they have special meaning.

Comment: As to the last paragraph try: `echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd" |sed 'N;N;N;s/\\`/<<</;s/\'\''/>>>/'` N.B. using single quotes around the sed command the `\'` has to be quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sed adds a trailing newline to the output **only if** there was a newline that it chopped off before placing that line in the pattern space.* This is documented in the info pages. Check here: [How sed Works](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle). Specifically,

> When the end of the script is reached, unless the -n option is in use, the contents of pattern space are printed out to the output stream, **adding back the trailing newline if it was removed**.

That is, if it has read the end of file without finding a newline character, it will just place the entire line in the pattern space (nothing chopped off here) and when outputting the pattern space, it won't add a new line either (as nothing was removed at the first place). This is easy to demonstrate:

```
vivek@vivek-laptop:~ $ PS1=' $ '
 $ cat > /tmp/file
aa
aa $ sed 's/aa/bb/' /tmp/file
bb
bb $
```

I pressed ctrl-d after the second line, so there is no terminating  new line at the end of my file.

When doing the substitutions, sed will read the first `aa\n`, remove the `\n`, place `aa` in the pattern space, do the substitution (pattern space is now `bb`), output the pattern space, and add a `\n`. Hence, outputing `bb\n`.

When it reads the second line, it is looking for a newline or end-of-file to know when to stop reading the current line. It reads `aa` (without `\n`) , puts that in the pattern space, does the substitution and outputs the pattern space again. But doesn't add a `\n` this time as there was none that it removed when adding the line to the pattern space.

To explain your three scenarios:

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd" \
  | sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; ${g; s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)$/\1\x00\2\x00\3\x00/; p}'
```

In this case, the pattern space will be `aa\nbb\ncc\ndd` . This correctly matches your regex. Also, no `\n` will be appended to the output (as none is there at the end).

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n" \
  | sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; ${g; s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n$/\1\x00\2\x00\3\x00/; p}'
```

In this case again, the pattern space will be `aa\nbb\ncc\ndd` . This **does not match** your regex and so no substitutions are done. A `\n` is appeneded to output.

```
$ echo -en "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n" \
  | sed -rn '1h; 2,$ H; ${g; s/^(.*)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)$/\1\x00\2\x00\3\x00/; p}'
```

In this case again, the patten space will be `aa\nbb\ncc\ndd`. This matches your regex. Also, a `\n` is appened to output as there was one at the end of last line.